# Expect Script: Interrupted and Successful Connections both returns EOF

Tags: expect, eof, cisco

I'm trying to push a set of commands to Cisco devices. The last command, obviously is "exit".

How can I determine the difference between the two since both of them can be tracked through eof.

1. All commands have been pushed successfully.
2. The connection was interrupted while executing the commands due to network connectivity loss.

I'm currently using `expect_after/expect_before` to catch `eof`.

Here's the dummy command set:

```
!test
!test
!test
!test
!test
!test
!LAST!!!!
exit

My expect_before statement:

expect_before {
    eof {
        RGenerateLog "${logdir}sendconfig-error.log" "${logprefix} Connection was interrupted."
        exit 11
    }
}

SCENARIO 1 (Successful):

sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!test
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#!LAST!!!!
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#exit
Connection closed by foreign host.

Log:
2015-05-27 12:32:13 [cisco.exp]: User=XXXXXXXX; Device=10.218.8.199; Action=config_change - Connection was interrupted.

SCENARIO 2 (Interrupted - I've closed the connection explicitly in the firewall):

sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#
sw05-00-00-2960.1194.POE#Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@tritone /tritone/system/send-config]# 

2015-05-27 12:35:40 [cisco.exp]: User=XXXXXXXX; Device=10.218.8.199; Action=config_change - Connection was interrupted
```

So my problem is, how will I know if all the commands were successfully pushed?

Comment: This question is particularly confusing. How can you determine the difference between the two of what? You only mention the 'exit' command. Are there two? What are the two errors that you posted at random. Are you getting these errors when trying to push the exit command?

Comment: Hi leigero, I've added more information.

Comment: Sending  `exit ` command will obviously close the connection, thereby `expect ` sees an `eof`.

Comment: I see, so the only solution is to close the spawned telnet process from expect explicitly. Do not exit from Cisco CLI, Thanks!